# Checkboxes inside scrollable div are being shown outside of it but the code works fine on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

My JS code is supposed to generate an html scrollable div with a form containing a list of checkboxes and I printed the string to the console and this was the result (not formatted):

```
<div><div id='div_Fluxo_de_transitoFonteFluxo_de_transitoFonteinput4' style='padding-left:1em; height:100px; max-width: 215px; border:2px solid #ccc; overflow-y: scroll; '><form id='form_Fluxo_de_transitoFonte'><label><input type='checkbox' value='CMP'>CMP</input></label><br/><label><input type='checkbox' value='IdP'>IdP</input></label><br/><label><input type='checkbox' value='PSP'>PSP</input></label><br/><label><input type='checkbox' value='Heli1'>Heli1</input></label><br/><label><input type='checkbox' value='Brisa'>Brisa</input></label><br/><label><input type='checkbox' value='Heli2'>Heli2</input></label><br/></form></div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k63o30ka/

The code generated works on jsfiddle but in my widget the checkboxes are shown outside the scrollable div:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/80494dcbb220424d94ebd3ba629c5698.png

Any ideas what may be causing this?
Note that the code is exactly the same in both cases.

UPDATE: The problem had to do with bootstrap used on the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks great. The only problem I see is, the outer `div` should have a `overflow: hidden`

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
  <div id='div_Fluxo_de_transitoFonteFluxo_de_transitoFonteinput4' style='padding-left:1em; height:100px; max-width: 215px; border:2px solid #ccc; overflow-y: scroll; '>
.....
</div>
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/8xknfevx/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is still there, the checkboxes are shown outside the container even though the respective labels are not